# Run program from standard user as a root

Tags: c, linux

I just created C program that require a root to privileges run properly. I want to execute it using special keybindings in my regular user account, so is there any way that I can give the program root permission and execute it with my regular user without typing sudo??
I already tried to change the owner ship to the root user and adding s mode to the user but it didn't help. Any ideas??
Here is the code:

```
/*
*This program will make some cleaning that i regularly do, 
*before the full system backup. And then itll create new dir 
*in my HDD with date to make the system backup in it useng rsync.
*The program will use system() to connect all the command line tools
*together and automate this process.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEV_PATH "/run/media/yan/HDD/"

void delete_dir(char *);
void get_date(int *);
char *make_backup_dir(const char *, int *);
void backup_sys(char *);

int main() {
    char *dirs_to_clean[] = {
        "/home/yan/.cache/spotify", "/home/yan/.cache/yay/*", 
        "/home/yan/.cache/mozilla/firefox/9jizeht4.default-release/cache2", "\0"
        };
    char *backup_path_ptr;
    int date[3]; //Array for the date of today
    int i;

    //System cleaning 
    for(i=0; *dirs_to_clean[i]!='\0'; i++) //Delete every dir in the dirs_to_clean array
        delete_dir(dirs_to_clean[i]);
    system("paccache -rk2");
    //System backup
    get_date(date); //Get the date of today and pass it to the array 
    backup_path_ptr = make_backup_dir(DEV_PATH, date); //Create backup dir and get its path
    backup_sys(backup_path_ptr); //Backup system to the backup_path_ptr dir
    return 0;
}

/*
*This function will delete the given argument dir.
*/
void delete_dir(char *dir_path) {
    char command_buffer[100];

    //Copy command to buffer (rm -rf dir_path) to delete dir.
    strcpy(command_buffer, "rm -rf ");
    strcat(command_buffer, dir_path);

    system(command_buffer); //Execute command
}

/*
*This function will get the date of today, and it'll insert it to the passed date array.
*/
void get_date(int *date) {
    long int sec_since_epoch;
    struct tm current_time, *time_ptr;

    sec_since_epoch = time(0); 
    time_ptr = &current_time; //Set time pointer to the current_time struct
    localtime_r(&sec_since_epoch, time_ptr);

    //Pass today's date to the array 
    *date = time_ptr->tm_mday;
    *(date+1) = time_ptr->tm_mon + 1; //+1 because months range from 0 - 11
    *(date+2) =  time_ptr->tm_year - 100; //-100 because tm_year is the passed years since 1900
}

/*
*A function that gets pointer to int array that contains the
*date of today and it converts it to string name so itll create
*a backup dir in the passed path with converted string.
*Then it will return the full path of the created dir to 
*make backup in it.
*/
char *make_backup_dir(const char *device_path, int *date_array) {
    int i;
    char dir_name[9], command_buffer[100];
    static char full_path[50]; //The returned full path 

    strcpy(command_buffer, "mkdir "); //Insert command to the command_buffer
    strcpy(full_path, device_path);
    //Convert the date_array to a strin so will use it to name the dir
    sprintf(dir_name, "%02d", *date_array);
    sprintf((dir_name+3), "%02d", *(date_array+1));
    sprintf(dir_name, "%02d", *date_array);
    sprintf(dir_name+6, "%d", *(date_array+2));
    dir_name[2] = dir_name[5] = '-';
    strcat(full_path, dir_name); //Complete the full dir path 
    strcat(command_buffer, full_path); //Complete the command
    system(command_buffer); //Execute the command 

    return full_path;
}

/*
*This function will make the full system backup using rsync to the passed dir.
*/
void backup_sys(char *backup_path) {
    const char *backup_command = "rsync -aAXHv --exclude={\"/dev/*\",\"/proc/*\",\"/sys/*\",\"/tmp/*\",\"/run/*\",\"/mnt/*\",\"/media/*\",\"/lost+found\"} / ";
    char command_buffer[200];

    //Prepare command
    strcpy(command_buffer, backup_command);
    strcat(command_buffer, backup_path);
    system(command_buffer);
}
```

Comment: This type of escalation is very hard to do programmatically on purpose.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I saw you said something about adding 's mode', which I took to mean you already set the 'setuid' permission on the executable.

Comment: I actually thought of that. So maybe it's better to give up running the program using keybindings and just run it from command-line using sudo ??

Comment: Its ok no problem, thanks for trying at least ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't help"? Did you call `set[r]euid()`? Can we see the code that didn't work.

Comment: I just posted it @David Schwartz

Answer (score 1):

As @thatotherguy said, the solution is add `setuid(geteuid());` to the code, plus changing the ownership to root and giving the users s mode (setuid).

Update: As it was noted it is not recommended to use the setuid mode because it causes many security holes!

Answer (score 0):

This is main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  printf("My real UID is %d\n", getuid());
  printf("My effective UID is %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

Then:

```
gcc main.c -o main
sudo chown root:root main
sudo chmod 6711 main
./main
```

Output:

```
My real UID is 1234
My effective UID is 0
```

In other words, I'm still "really" myself (UID 1234) but I'm effectively root (UID 0).

Does this not work for you?

Update: Okay, it does.

Next step is to get rid of the `system` call because your root privileges won't carry over to the program you execute via system. (By the way, to understand the problem with this, consider that the shell is going to find `paccache` by looking at your PATH, which means that anyone who is able to arrange for a program called `paccache` to appear in your PATH could trick you into running it as root.)

The way to launch a process in Linux is to call `fork`, which will split the process into a parent and a child, then call `execl` in the child process. (`execl` will never return, so if you want to do stuff after child program ends, you need to do that in the parent.)

```
pid_t child_pid;
if (child_pid = fork()) {
  int child_status;
  // I'm the parent, wait for child to finish.
  wait(&child_status);
} else {
  // I'm the child; run the other program.
  execl("/path/to/paccache", "paccache", "-rk2", NULL);
}
// Do whatever you want to do after paccache ends...
```

For a non-trivial program you'd probably want to check for errors from `fork`, `wait`, `execl`, etc.

Comment: Well, you never change them, so of course they don't change. Did you try calling `seteuid()`? You need to specify *precisely* when and where you need the privileges and when it's safe to enable them. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Enable_002fDisable-Setuid.html) for more.

Comment: Nope i just tried to run a test c program that uses system() function to execute the command pacman -Syu... It didnt  work.

Comment: @yankh18 You have no code to change your effective user ID. Call `seteuid()` after the code that makes sure it's safe to raise permissions and before the code that needs elevated permissions.

Comment: My program is like wrapper program for rsync and few other command line tools to do all my full system backup and all the cleaning automatically.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is it necessary to call `seteuid` to acquire root privileges? I thought that the program *starts* with root privileges but that it's a "best practice" to switch back to the real user UID at the start of the program.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn It depends on precisely what your definition of "root privileges" are. But as you demonstrated, the effective user ID is not changed. The code *must* make sure it's safe to elevate before it elevates.

Comment: The effective UID *is* changed. It's UID 0, root.

Comment: I was able to do root-y things, like removing a file owned by root, in `main` without calling `seteuid`.

Comment: @yankh18 Using `system()` will drop suid (on systems where sh is bash). Please test with something else.

Comment: @yankh18 What happens if you compile and run this exact program with the commands shown? Does it show you that the effective UID is 0? That will at least tell you if you're able to run a setuid-root program.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, a process started from a setuid executable gets its effective UID from the program file, (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). That's also the UID that matters for pretty much everything related to permissions, though some _programs_ do test if real UID != effective UID and then complain about that. And yes, you could juggle the UIDs around, so that you don't need to keep EUID == 0 all the time, or you could just drop the privileges, i.e. set EUID to whatever the real UID is.

Comment: @that other guy im pretty sure that without the system() it works like the chsh tool.

Comment: @Willis Blackburn  yup effective uid is 0

Comment: @yankh18 "that other guy" is correct, even if your program is running as root, the shell launched by `system` will drop root privileges, so `paccache` will run as your regular user ID. You need to call `fork` and `execl` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, just do a `setuid(geteuid());` before the `system()` call

Comment: @Willis Blackburn OK thanks appreciate it, ill do some search about them and hopefully i would find a way to do it.

Comment: @that other guy wow that worked. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Please be aware that suid is hard to secure, and suid shells more so (that's why this feature is there). Your program currently has multiple security holes that lets any user run any command as root.

Comment: @thatotherguy That works but delivers root privileges to any program called `paccache` in the user's PATH. Probably okay in this case but... :-)

Comment: If you want to do things "right" a setuid program is almost never it. You need to do a list of checks and settings to be safe and even then you probably screwed it up. It's a better idea to launch it as root from cron or systemd. You could use a systemd sockets or DBUS trigger if you wanted.

Comment: After a bit of thinking i decided to run it as a root from command line because you guys are right, its risky to give it setuid permission and anyone can exploit it and take advantage of that using shellcode

Comment: Going to clean up these setuid-root executables I have lying around now...